# jQuery hide column based on searched string

Tags: jquery

i want to hide table column based on searched text(td). Something like this

```
jQuery("#searchTableInput2").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
   jQuery("#searchTable2 tr td:not(:contains('"+ value +"')")).('hide columns');
});
```

There is no such example through out internet. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: try with `jQuery("#searchTable2 tr td:not(:contains('"+ value +"')")).hide();` ?

Comment: do you wanna hide column or row?

Comment: This hides td which works fine. What i want is to hide whole column that does not contains searched string (text)

Comment: I want hide column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#searchTableInput2").on("keyup", function() {
    let searchKey = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#searchTable2 tr td,#searchTable2 tr th').show();
    if(searchKey == '') return;
    var colCount = $("#searchTable2 tr th").length;
    for (i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
      let keyExists = false;
      $('#searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+')').each( function(){
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)) {
          keyExists = true;
          return;
        }      
      });
      if(!keyExists) {
        $('#searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+'), #searchTable2 tr th:nth-child('+i+')').hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchTableInput2" value=""/>

<table id="searchTable2" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works just fine but let me make it work with key up and show the searched text column, not hide searched text column. Many many thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. I added what you want as well. You can check again.

Comment: Thanks again. The full text search does not work, like try to search 'Eve', it does not work. Anyways, i got the answer

Comment: To make case sensitive, try change two lines
1: let searchKey = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
2: if($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)) {

Comment: Added case insensitive too. Also, you can search full contents as well.

Comment: Great Work, Mr Murat

Comment: Hi @murat, I have another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63824594/jquery-filter-already-filtered-table-or-work-multiple-filters-at-a-time related to this qustion