# Filter already filtered table or work multiple filters at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with multiple filters, I want to filter columns and hide those that does not contains the searched keyword which works just fine but I want all filters to works at a time. The working table is here on this page
http://beta.flexxonsolutions.com/products/sata-iii/2-5-ssd-sata-iii-new1/

And the jQuery code

```
jQuery(".searchTableInput2").on("keyup", function() {
      let searchKey = jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase();
         
          jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td,.searchTable2 tr th').show();  
       
      if(searchKey == '') return;
      var colCount = jQuery(".searchTable2 tr th").length;
      for (i = 2; i <= colCount; i++) {
        let keyExists = false;
        jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+')').each( function(){
          if(jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)) {
            keyExists = true;
            return;
          }      
        });
        if(!keyExists) {
          jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+'), .searchTable2 tr th:nth-child('+i+')').hide();
        }
      }
    });

  //this is for search by flash
  jQuery(".searchFlashInput").on("change", function() {
      let searchKey = jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase();
      jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td,.searchTable2 tr th').show();
      if(searchKey == '') return;
      var colCount = jQuery(".searchTable2 tr th").length;
      for (i = 2; i <= colCount; i++) {
        let keyExists = false;
        jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+')').each( function(){
          if(jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase().split(', ').includes(searchKey)) {
            keyExists = true;
            return;
          }      
        });
        if(!keyExists) {
          jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+'), .searchTable2 tr th:nth-child('+i+')').hide();
        }
      }
    });

  //this is for search by features
  jQuery(".searchGradeInput").on("change", function() {
      let searchKey = jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase();
      jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td,.searchTable2 tr th').show();

      var test = [];
      if(searchKey == '') return;
      var colCount = jQuery(".searchTable2 tr th").length;
      for (i = 2; i <= colCount; i++) {
        let keyExists = false;
        jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+')').each( function(){
          if(jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)) {
            keyExists = true;
            return;
          }      
        });
        if(!keyExists) {
          jQuery('.searchTable2 tr td:nth-child('+i+'), .searchTable2 tr th:nth-child('+i+')').hide();
        }
     }
  });

       //reset button function
       jQuery('.tble_reset_filters').click(function(){
         jQuery('.searchFlashInput')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
         jQuery('.searchGradeInput')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
         jQuery('.searchTableInput2').val('');
         jQuery('.searchTableInput2').keyup();
       });
```

Comment: it looks you solved the problem when I visited the link you gave?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your time